# Python - Pandas - Error while importing pandas

Tags: python, pandas, installation

Getting error on importing pandas :

Error details:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'maybe_box_datetimelike' from 
'pandas.core.dtypes.cast' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py)
```

Installed it using `pip install pandas`

Comment: Maybe you should use conda? conda install pandas

Comment: try uninstalling and again installing pandas

Comment: @VictorErmakov tried, same error

Comment: Please mention your `pandas` version

Comment: @BhavyaParikh pandas version 1.2.4

Comment: You can go through this [thread](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/6770)  from github